# last inserted row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I executed a query which will insert an image link and username into a table:

```
INSERT into pictures set src = 'image link', username = 'acc'
```

I want to display that image after the query is executed (from table), or to get `ID` (I tried `mysql_insert_id()`, but what if 3 or more users will execute the query at the same time, which id will I get?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It gets the last ID from **your** database session, so if other users insert, that does not matter :D.

As long as your session does not do other insert (thats quite unlikely in mosts systems) in between you're fine

Comment: thanks for the answer it will help me alot and will save a lot of my time.

Comment: Just be sure that you don't do other things like updates in between: they're queries too, so you'll "lose" your last_inserted_id. Just query it directly (query-wise, time is not an issue) after your INSERT (new comment to fix a typo in the old one from 2011)